# How to fix error CS1061 in unity3d in my case? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting the same error over and over. I watched a lot of videos on youtube and I searched on google, but I can not find the solution to this error by myself.

I fixed this problem a month ago, but it came back again, I forgot what I did to fix it.

Console:
[image]

Code:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get components from GameObjects, not from components itself.

`collisionInfo.gameObject.GetComponent...`

Also, it seems like all of those objects with the pre-defined names do the same action.
You can give all of those objects a pre-defined tag instead, that way you can simply use one if-statement over multiple.

Like so:

```
// Give all of the respective game-objects with a tag of 'LoadMainCollisionHelper'
if (collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("LoadMainCollisionHelper")){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("MainCollision");
}
```

P.S: Please post the code instead, instead of snapping a picture of it.

Comment: Do you mean I should add a tag to all those objects? I will post the code next time, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, check Unity's doc on [Tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) if you didn't knew about that. The reason behind it is so that you can easily add a new game-object that can load the `maincollision` scene without changing and rebuilding the code.

Comment: I knew about tags, but never realize that I could use it here. Thanks!